# jQuery UI Dialog Box, wont close or execute

Tags: jquery

For the life of me I can't work out when the script wont execute when the Yes button is clicked?

Nothing recorded in Console.

Can someone help please?! :)

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/MCam435/NYWg2/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="reqtalkdialog" title="Confirmation Required">
  Would you like to request contact?
</div>

<div id="reqtalk100006" style="display:block"><a href="#" class="reqtalk" id="100006">
<span class="reqtalk_b"> + Talk </span></a></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#reqtalkdialog").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   modal: true,
   buttons : {
        "Yes" : function() {
            var element = $(this);
            var I = element.attr("id");
            var info = 'id=' + I;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "resource/talkrequest.php",
                data: info,
                success: function(){}
            });

            $("#reqtalk"+I).hide();
            $("#talking"+I).show();
            return false;

            $(this).dialog("close");           
            },

        "Cancel" : function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });

$(".reqtalk").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#reqtalkdialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Why are you returning false before dialog close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning false before closing the dialog.

Remove that line, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/A6TbN/

```
$("#reqtalkdialog").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
   modal: true,
   buttons : {
    "Yes" : function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + I;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "resource/talkrequest.php",
            data: info,
            success: function(){}
        });

        $("#reqtalk"+I).hide();
        $("#talking"+I).show();
        // return false;            

        $(this).dialog("close");

        },

    "Cancel" : function() {
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }
  }
});

$(".reqtalk").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#reqtalkdialog").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Arghh, I knew it was something silly. Now I need to work out why I had return false in there in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: Have just realised, after removing return false, it prevents the show/hide bits from working? Originally i wrote the script with the Yes option as standalone script, and tried to include it into the dialog afterwards.

Comment: Just to clarify, the talking class isn't actually in the fiddle, but the reqtalk should still hide?

Comment: @Mcam435 That code for showing/hiding is not working for a different issue. Try putting a `console.log(I)` and I think you'll see that `I` is not what you think it is.

Comment: Ah yes... it's picking up 'reqtalkdialog' instead of 'reqtalk100006'... How am I going to pick up 'reqtalk100006'? It's created by PHP script so I can't target by name (the whole idea in picking it up by jQuery).